# get certain where condition results first from multiple where condtions in laravel

Tags: laravel, sorting, eloquent

I have query like below which has 2 where conditions, but i want to get the result of first where condition first and then i want to get second where condition's result also,

so how do i sort the results like that:

```
Post::where('title','like',"%google%")->orWhereHas('tags', function (Builder $query){
  $query->where('name', 'like', "%google%");
})->take(10)->get();
```

i want to **get posts which contains `google` in it's title first then i also want to get posts which contains `tags` with `google` in its `name`, how to sort like that in Laravel?**

Thanks in advance.

**update:** corrected the tags field name.

Comment: Please try like below, `Post::where('title','like',"%google%")->orWhereHas('tags', function (Builder $query){
  $query->where('title', 'like', "%google%");
})->where('tags.title','like',"%google%")->take(10)->get();`

Comment: @NikleshRaut, My query is working fine, but the problem is results of tag's where condition comes first, but i want to get post.title's where condition's results first, and your query just double the where condition of tags title.

Comment: @NikleshRaut I have updated my question, tags table has `name` field and post table has title field, sorry for confusion.

Comment: So did you try with `'tags.name'` in place of `'tags.title'` ?

Comment: I think you should use query builder with join instead eloquent

Comment: @NikleshRaut, No i have `tags.name` but mistakenly i have added title instead of name, yes i also think query builder can do it, but it is the last option, i am finding the way with the eloquent, if it has any.